# Javascript toLocaleString is ignoring timezone and locale

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a date iun the ISO format, and convert it to a local time, however it just comes back with UTC.

Here is my code:

```
var date =  new Date().toISOString();
var timeZone = "Europe/London";
var locale = "en-GB";
var localDate = new Date(date.toLocaleString(locale, { timeZone: timeZone }));
console.log(localDate);
```

My intentions are for this to log the current GB time, however its an hour previous which I assume is UTC.

Comment: I'm in the UK, I just tried you code in the console, I do get the "right time": `Wed May 06 2020 15:53:50 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`.

Comment: @sp00m thats weird, this is my output: 2020-05-06T14:56:07.403Z,
I expect 2020-05-06T15:56:07.403Z

Comment: `2020-05-06T14:56:07.403Z` is the same instant, that's just UTC time (`Z`ulu), `2020-05-06T15:56:07.403Z` would be in one hour (still UTC). Do you need to format that same instant in Europe/London timezone like the output I have?

Comment: @sp00m yeah, so shouldn't the conversion im doing with date.toLocaleString bring it to BST? - I do need it to be formatted the way that I have it

Comment: Use `momentjs` instead, it handles zone and locale automatically for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The final `Z` is for Zulu time, aka UTC, so you cannot expect `2020-05-06T15:56:07.403Z` when asking for _now_, because it's actually in the future.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting that output at all, when I am using date.toLocaleString and passing in the time zones and locale which i require, why is it coming back with UTC at all?

Comment: Is your system clock wrong?

Comment: @MattEllen Nope (currently 16:11 BST)

Comment: Are you sure that time zone tag is correct? The only thing that JavaScript implementations **must** recognize is "UTC".  It could be that your time zone string is just being ignored.

Comment: @Pointy It seems correct to me, this implementation which I have posted above has previously worked.

Comment: Wait wait: you initialize `date` to the **string** version of the current timestamp. The code as posted should not work at all; it should throw an error because `.toLocaleString()` is not a String prototype method.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. Just gonna bite the bullet and use moments.js.